# Sql update takes 4 days for 10 million records

Tags: oracle, plsql, query-performance

I want to update a database table which has over 10 million records from a temporary table.
But my update query executes more than 4 days.

1.) I have already created an index for update search criteria for 
    tax_ledger_item_tab. index creatred on party_type, identity, company.
    My search criteria are on party_type, identity, company, delivery_type_id 
    as the following given query, those columns are not keys in the table.

I believe that I  cant add delivery_type_id for the index as it will 
update by the query, if I add that into index performance will be worst.

2.) temporary table identity_invoice_info_cfv will also returns 70,000 records 
    also.

So far I believe my update execution plan cost will be like around 70000*10 million records.

How can I get performance enhancement with following update query? I only want to update delivery_type_id, fetched columns only.

```
DECLARE

CURSOR get_records IS
  SELECT i.COMPANY, i.IDENTITY, i.CF$_DELIVERY_TYPE
    FROM identity_invoice_info_cfv i
   WHERE i.PARTY_TYPE_DB = 'CUSTOMER';

BEGIN

  FOR rec_ IN get_records LOOP
  dbms_output.put_line  (sysdate ); 

    UPDATE tax_ledger_item_tab t
       SET t.delivery_type_id = rec_.CF$_DELIVERY_TYPE, t.fetched = 'TRUE'
     WHERE t.party_type = 'CUSTOMER'
       AND t.identity = rec_.IDENTITY
       AND t.company = rec_.COMPANY
       AND t.delivery_type_id IS NULL;

    COMMIT;  

  END LOOP;

 END;
```

Comment: Why using a cursor ??

Comment: I agree with Patrick. Using a single UPDATE statement with a single commit is likely to be faster

Comment: temporary table data will read by the cursor and it loop through entire records.
Is there any workaround to enhance this update criteria?

Comment: So this cursor requires to fetch data from the tempory table and to update tax_ledger_item_tab with cursor reading values.

Comment: Yes, as per the above code tempory table reading column value CF$_DELIVERY_TYPE  taken to update tax_ledger_item_tab.delivery_type_id

Comment: I meant, do you use it any **outside of this piece of code**?

Comment: No, I do not use this piece of code outside, This is the only code segment uses to update tax_ledger_item_tab table

Comment: You can use MERGE Statement [https://oracle-base.com/articles/9i/merge-statement]

Comment: Upvoted just because it's a valid question and doesn't deserve downvotes. Share the knowledge.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a `MERGE` statement:

**Oracle Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE identity_invoice_info_cfv ( COMPANY, IDENTITY, CF$_DELIVERY_TYPE, PARTY_TYPE_DB ) AS
SELECT 'A', 123, 456, 'CUSTOMER' FROM DUAL;

CREATE TABLE tax_ledger_item_tab ( identity, company, party_type, delivery_type_id, fetched ) AS
SELECT 123, 'A', 'CUSTOMER', CAST( NULL AS NUMBER ), 'FALSE' FROM DUAL;
```

**Merge**:

```
MERGE INTO tax_ledger_item_tab t
USING identity_invoice_info_cfv i
ON (
    t.identity      = i.identity
AND t.company       = i.COMPANY
AND t.party_type    = 'CUSTOMER'
AND i.PARTY_TYPE_DB = 'CUSTOMER'
)
WHEN MATCHED THEN
  UPDATE
  SET delivery_type_id = i.CF$_DELIVERY_TYPE,
      fetched          = 'TRUE'
  WHERE t.delivery_type_id IS NULL;
```

**Query**:

```
SELECT * FROM tax_ledger_item_tab;
```

**Output**:

```
IDENTITY | COMPANY | PARTY_TYPE | DELIVERY_TYPE_ID | FETCHED
-------: | :------ | :--------- | ---------------: | :------
     123 | A       | CUSTOMER   |              456 | TRUE
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=a66bf2a703932f4e8d9f44540b83b58f)*

Comment: I got significant improvement with this query only took 102 minutes to execute this 10 million records.

Answer (score 2):

I hope you can achieve this using Merge Statement as well. Below is the code for the same. Please test from your side with some sample data and then proceed.

```
  Merge into tax_ledger_item_tab t
  using identity_invoice_info_cfv i
      on (t.party_type ='CUSTOMER' and t.identity=i.IDENTITY 
         and t.company = i.COMPANY  and i.PARTY_TYPE_DB = 'CUSTOMER')
       when matched then
             update set  
              t.delivery_type_id=i.CF$_DELIVERY_TYPE,
              t.fetched = 'TRUE' 
            where t.delivery_type_id IS NULL;
        commit;
```

Comment: This gives an exception `ORA-38104: Columns referenced in the ON Clause cannot be updated: "T"."DELIVERY_TYPE_ID"`

Comment: `t.delivery_type_id IS NULL` This needs to be removed in the on clause. I have updated the script